# The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-10

Solution is not Building
MVC Solution containing 6 Projects
Same code and configurations are working fine for my peer but not for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLZNJ.png)
Can somebody guide me what's problem

Answer (score 0):

It was a visual Studio issue.
I was using visual-studio 2015 and solution was not compiling 
I switched to visual-studio 2019 and Solution Compiled

Issue has been resolved and working fine for me but can anyone tell me what's the actual reason behind it???